# Subtracting values in the same row and column but in different dataframe files

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two data sets that have many columns. I want to subtract values in the same row and column number for all the data points. Here is a fraction of how the two data looks like.

Data 1:

```
4   6   8
4403    4403    4403
4640    4640    4640
0   0   0
12  0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
127 60  60
357 275 317
1882    2144    1838
6726    6609    7915
9398    11180   12737
12784   18389   21361
15863   20111   24469
6739    10202   11897
1684    1921    2735
249 376 476
47  103 70
0   26  82
17  0   18
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   18
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   12
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   18
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
12  0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   12
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
12  0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
13  0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   13
```

Data2:

```
4   6   8
4400    4400    4400
4750    4750    4750
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   25  12
0   0   12
12  13  0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
12  0   12
0   0   0
24  0   18
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   12  0
39  0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   12  12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
43  46  13
6711    11323   9375
91043   116679  123466
241572  307822  310620
250588  309749  314146
105123  139651  141462
16143   21264   23856
2521    3648    3243
1042    1022    1598
576 910 525
482 552 509
229 416 425
210 227 264
120 149 99
69  55  58
47  0   17
26  65  29
0   20  35
0   0   32
0   0   14
0   12  12
12  38  12
0   0   0
18  0   12
0   0   0
0   13  0
0   0   0
0   18  0
16  0   12
12  0   0
0   0   12
12  0   12
0   0   0
0   23  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
20  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   12  12
14  12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   18  0
0   0   0
12  0   39
12  0   12
13  0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
24  0   14
0   15  0
0   16  0
0   12  0
12  0   12
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
14  13  0
0   23  24
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   16  0
0   12  0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   13  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
16  0   0
0   12  21
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  13
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   19  12
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   12  12
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  24  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   12  0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   29
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   0   0
0   12  0
12  12  0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   12
0   12  0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   12
13  16  12
24  17  0
0   0   0
12  0   41
0   0   0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
14  12  0
25  0   0
0   12  0
0   0   0
0   15  0
0   0   0
12  0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   25
27  0   0
0   12  0
0   22  0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

For all the data, the column names are '4', '6', '8'.

So between the data 1 and 2, the first subtraction for the row 1 in column '4' would be=4403-4400.

It is easier to do one individually but I am looking for a way to do this for all columns efficiently..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the first five rows of your output look like?

Comment: `df1 - df2`? Since it seems they have the same columns and indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Here are two answers. The short one as pointed out above:

`result = Data1 - Data2`

And a more lengthy answer that you might need if you want to replace subtraction with more complicated calculations. It creates the result DataFrame first. It assumes that Data1 and Data2 are the same shape. As is common in Python, there are other ways to do this, too. I tested it this time. :-)

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['4','6','8'], index = Data1.index)
for index, row in Data1.iterrows():
    for col in Data1.columns:
        result.iloc[index][col] = Data1.iloc[index][col] - Data2.iloc[index][col]
print (result)
```

Comment: Hi, the issue I'm running into is with the 'result'. The error message I get is "undefined name 'result'"